# Can't get edge transport to receive internet mail

Tags: exchange-2013, exchange

I am upgrading an Exchange 2007 environment to Exchange 2013.  Temporarily, while I complete the upgrade, I have both an Exchange 2k7 and a new Exchange 2013  Edge Transport server and MailBox server in my environment.

Internet email to the new Exchange 2013 Edge transport server is not arriving at the mailboxes on the new Exchange 2013 Mailbox server..

I have Exchange 2013 mail box server and Edge Transport server installed and set up on separate VMs. 
I have created an EdgeSubscription Info xml file and installed it on the Mailbox as specified in 
[MSDN Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997438%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).  I still have old Exchange 2007 edge transport server and mailbox server running, and mailboxes on the old 2k7 server are still able to receive mail when I direct firewall to NAT incoming smtp to the old 2k7 edge box. When I switch firewall NAT to send incoming smtp to the new 2013 Edge transport server, no mail is received by the mailbox server, and the sending server receives an undeliverable message from the new 2013 Edge server (so I know the packets are arriving at the new edge transport server).  The DNR report mentions

***"451 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX2"***

When I run `Get-EdgeSUbscription` I see both the old 2k7 subscription (Server name EDGE) and the new 2013 subscription (Server name Hermes).  When I ran `Start-EdgeSynchronization` on the new 2013 mailbox server the output showed both subscriptions, as follows:

I don't understand why each subscription is listed twice, but the new one is the third and fourth, and seems to have started and connected successfully.

```
RunspaceId     : b7f7fc57-1f9a-4cb8-a59a-5960ae6a0856
Result         : CouldNotConnect
Type           : Configuration
Name           : Edge
FailureDetails :
StartUTC       : 4/14/2014 4:43:58 PM
EndUTC         : 4/14/2014 4:43:58 PM
Added          : 0
Deleted        : 0
Updated        : 0
Scanned        : 0
TargetScanned  : 0

RunspaceId     : b7f7fc57-1f9a-4cb8-a59a-5960ae6a0856
Result         : CouldNotConnect
Type           : Recipients
Name           : Edge
FailureDetails :
StartUTC       : 4/14/2014 4:43:58 PM
EndUTC         : 4/14/2014 4:43:58 PM
Added          : 0
Deleted        : 0
Updated        : 0
Scanned        : 0
TargetScanned  : 0

RunspaceId     : b7f7fc57-1f9a-4cb8-a59a-5960ae6a0856
Result         : Success
Type           : Recipients
Name           : Hermes
FailureDetails :
StartUTC       : 4/14/2014 4:43:58 PM
EndUTC         : 4/14/2014 4:43:58 PM
Added          : 0
Deleted        : 0
Updated        : 0
Scanned        : 0
TargetScanned  : 0

RunspaceId     : b7f7fc57-1f9a-4cb8-a59a-5960ae6a0856
Result         : Success
Type           : Configuration
Name           : Hermes
FailureDetails :
StartUTC       : 4/14/2014 4:43:58 PM
EndUTC         : 4/14/2014 4:43:58 PM
Added          : 0
Deleted        : 0
Updated        : 0
Scanned        : 0
TargetScanned  : 0
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had an external dns as a third alternate dns address in my network adapoter IP4 settings.  See this [TechNet link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/fc23776c-bae4-4ca9-ad6d-4f8df880f47c/451-470-temporary-server-error-please-try-again-later-prx2?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaging) for details.